# Is it possible to establish full VPN between 2 windows machines using ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

Okay, I have asked this question in a different way [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/715122/alternatives-to-make-remote-connections-to-office-network-vpn-work-when-port-172) but I am confused and wanted to ask it in a different way:

Is it possible to establish a VPN connection between two windows machines using no other method of transport but SSH ?

I am not talking about a port based VPN, as in, you need to specify a port on the source to access on the traget machine. I am hoping to find a way to establish a full VPN connection, so that my VPN  client machine will have an IP address on the VPN server's network. At which point I will be able to use any software as if I am on the remote network.

What is available to me and my associated problems with those:

Logmein was working when it was free, now it went to the pay way and price they are asking don't justfy my use

Teamwiewer was working, but the workplace firewall changed from Bluecoat to websense and the connections to addresses ending with teamviewer.com are being blocked

TightVNC server works but it has problems as follows:
a) when I open some system tools, VNC don't work well with them (example: Win Job scheduler) I lose all my keybord ability. And when the keyboard functions, it messes up ctrl, alt and shift key combinations often. Especially when I am using chrome browser and autohotkey and need some hot key combinations on the remote end.

b) it doesn't work with ports other than 5800 and 5900, so I can only connect to one single machine and when it goes belly up (due to reason stated in paragraph a or any other thing) I am SOL

Comment: Have you discussed you requirements about remote access with your systems admin, or are you the systems admin?  What firewall are you using? Can you get a VPN account on your firewall?

Comment: Okay, read your other post.  From what I understand, you are trying to PPTP vpn out from a clients site to your own site.  Have you asked your clients to open outbound 1723 for you?  Tunnelling using ssh is not pretty.  You could do something like this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH

Comment: Unfortunately, client's network operations are outsourced and getting a minor change for business purposes, takes upwards of 2 weeks, I am sure they will not accomodate my request and I am not the only one on this boat. Security is a very big concern there and they will not be willing to poke holes in their firewalls for a few measly consultants.

Comment: Then I would advise you not to attempt to circumvent their security measures.  It is grounds to fire someone with cause.  If found staff deliberately circumventing our security measures they would face severe disciplinary measures.